# XPATH Testing string value of child and parent has empty string value

Tags: selenium, xpath, custom-selectors

I have html that I am searching against in a Selenium test where I want to find the child by its text *only if the parent has no text*:

Here's the HTML:

```
    <ul>
     <li>
      <div>
      "4"
       <span>630</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <div>

       <span>630</span>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <div>
     "6"
      <span>630</span>
     </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

Selecting for the text string '630' yields three results using "//span[.='630']" or "//span[text()='630']", but I only want that middle one with an empty parent. I've tried a whole lot of constructions that don't work `"//span[.='630' and parent::div[.='']]"` or `"//span[text()='630' and parent::div[text='']]"` and even `"//div[text()='']/*[1] | //span[text()='630']"` but these all result in either 3 results or none.

Note that while `"//span[text()='630'] and .//div[contains(text(),'')]"` *detects* the text, it returns true, and I need it to return the element so that I can click it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//span[text()='630']/parent::div[not(text())]
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
//div[@innertext='']/span[text()='630']
```